# Correct definition for 'arg' in mathematical logic

Tags: logic, model-theory

I am currently reading *Logic of Mathematics* by Sofia Adamowicz and Paweł Zbierski, and the following definition is given

$$\textrm{arg}(r)=n \textrm{ if and only if } r\subset A^n$$
however, it seems to follow then that the argument function is not well-defined for the empty set.

Likewise

$$\textrm{arg}(f)=n \textrm{ if and only if dom}(f)= A^n$$
and this also seems not well-defined for the empty function.  Is there a canonical way to handle this.  I ask because it affects the answer I give to one of the problems in the textbook, and I'd prefer to have the `right' one.

Comment: It's more common to assign first the number of arguments to each function/relation *symbol*, and then their interpretations in a given model must satisfy the criteria you give.

Comment: So in this book we haven't yet discussed models or interpretations (that is much later); so while I am not entirely lost by your response...  I'm not entirely sure it answers my question.  

Are you simply suggesting that arg of the empty set and arg of the empty function should be simply zero?

Comment: Not exactly. Well, the empty function doesn't have domain $=A^n$ (unless $A$ itself is empty). The empty relation, otherwise, can be considered with arbitrary arity.

Comment: But see page 9 : $A^n$ is defined for $n \ge 1$.

Comment: IIRC, the custom is that $A^0 = \emptyset$ for any set $A$.